# Sidekiq looking for en.yml file in older capistrano release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, capistrano3

I am running `sidekiq` in production and I deploy my app using `capistrano`. While processing background job, I am getting following error

`I18n::InvalidLocaleData: can not load translations from /path/to/folder/releases/20160904153949/config/locales/en.yml: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /path/to/folder/releases/20160904153949/config/locales/en.yml>`.

release `20160904153949` is old and has been deleted. I am wondering why sidekiq is still looking into older release.

Below is how my `deploy.rb` file looks like:

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'app_name'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:reboot/app_name.git'

# Default branch is :master
set :branch, 'master'

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/path/to/app'

set :use_sudo, false
set :bundle_binstubs, nil

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/assets')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5
set :keep_assets, 3

after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'

namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end
end
```

Below is how my `Capfile` looks like

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rvm'

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/sidekiq'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

sidekiq stop/start is handled by `capistrano/sidekiq` gem. My app gets deployed fine. Problem is that sidekiq is looking into wrong release for required file.

Also I don't have `sidekiq.yml` file at this stage. My app is small so never created yml file for it.

Ruby: 2.3.0p0,
Rails: 4.2.5,
nginx/passenger combination,
Capistrano 3.4

**Upadate**

Below is full error message:

```
2016-09-07T19:33:22.349Z 3262 TID-md1a4 ContactUsEmailJob JID-fb18ad450d73ed857fe66aee INFO: fail: 0.069 sec

2016-09-07T19:33:22.350Z 3262 TID-md1a4 WARN: {"class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","wrapped":"ContactUsEmailJob","queue":"default","args":[{"job_class":"ContactUsEmailJob","job_id":"e30dfe20-89b2-49a9-833c-8e479bdb8a2d","queue_name":"default","arguments":[{"utf8":"✓","authenticity_token":"i+OuDyC2c243UvC0FRWk1esASnUhQ2jKbfvZnoX2GZLela+mPCcOU6qtpU3OZhxr0wTCYUpmFXD6623Q==","name":"Test","message":"test","controller":"static_pages","action":"email_us","_aj_hash_with_indifferent_access":true}],"locale":"en"}],"retry":true,"jid":"fb18ad450d73ed857fe66aee","created_at":1473276802.277088,"enqueued_at":1473276802.2773373,"error_message":"can not load translations from /path/to/app/releases/20160904153949/config/locales/en.yml: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /path/to/app/releases/20160904153949/config/locales/en.yml>","error_class":"I18n::InvalidLocaleData","failed_at":1473276802.3480363,"retry_count":0}

2016-09-07T19:33:22.350Z 3262 TID-md1a4 WARN: I18n::InvalidLocaleData: can not load translations from /path/to/app/releases/20160904153949/config/locales/en.yml: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /path/to/app/releases/20160904153949/config/locales/en.yml>

2016-09-07T19:33:22.350Z 3262 TID-md1a4 WARN: /path/to/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:184:in `rescue in load_yml'
```

Comment: Give the full backtrace.  Sidekiq doesn't load `config/locale` files so this must be something else in your app.

Comment: @MikePerham done. I have updated question with full backtrace. Thanks

Comment: that's not the full backtrace.  a backtrace should have dozens of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved the problem by following these steps:

- kill process of sidekiq `pkill sidekiq`
- deleted sidekiq pid file from `/path/to/app/current/tmp/pid/`
- started sidekiq using `cap sidekiq:start`, this will create pid file
- finally deploy my app ( this process will restart sidekiq again)

Everything worked find after that.